# Prompt email notifications for a Content Health review gives urgency to a non-urgent task

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams

I like getting prompt email notifications for getting a comment or an answer in Stack Overflow for Teams, because it's likely to be relevant to something that I'm working on right now - I've got it set to 5 minutes.

However, I don't like getting prompt email notifications about content health reviews, within five minutes of it appearing on the website. The post being reviewed is probably months old, and may well be obsolete - in fact, that's one reason its content health is being reviewed.

I'm about to set up an email filter for emails with "content health review" in their body and have Outlook not alert me if I get such an email, but there might be a more logical way of handling content health reviews.

Comment: I too would like to stop these annoying "Content Health" review emails. I turned off all for you emails now, good by all notifications.