# How to turn off Stack Overflow content health emails

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

I am getting spammed with Stack Overflow's team "[Content Health](https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/5738804-content-health)" emails—how do I opt out of these?

I still need team emails and just don't want "Content Health" ones that are years old.

Thanks everyone I was able to create a rule to delete them
where "is due for a Content Health review" is in the body

Comment: Is it not in with the other email settings?

Comment: first placed I looked, I still need team emails, just don't want content health ones

Comment: OK; it's helpful to include that context when asking.

Comment: AFIAK there's no way to opt out of _just_ the Content Health emails but still receive other notifications. Also related [Prompt email notifications for a Content Health review gives urgency to a non-urgent task](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416514/15497888)

Comment: I've never gotten one of these, are you the owner of a Team?

Comment: What is content health?

Comment: @Dharman It's a review queue for posts that haven't been active recently to ensure they're still relevant, available to users with enough privileges on business tier. (See link I added to the post.)

Comment: If can't opt out, can always create a Rule in E-Mail Client to automatically delete those Mails... :idea:

Comment: I did not see anything in the email subject or body that indicates content health.  Email appears to be a new pressing issue that needs to addressed and then upon navigating to it you find out that its a year old

Comment: @Steve - Sounds like the review queue that’s been described

Comment: @chivracq - I found 1 small comment in the email that I was able to create a rule on, thanks

Comment: Yeah, well, then you can maybe post your Rule as an Answer/Solution, you possibly won't be the "only one" getting annoyed by those Mails..., and that might "incite" the Developers to add some 'Opt Out' Setting/Option to that Func/Notif... (Or they'll change the Sentence/Keyword(s) you used for the Rule, ah-ah...! [Spam + Anti-Spam] is often a "Cat & Mouse" Game...!)