# Please allow me to turn off Teams weekly email digests without turning off emails about answers/comments on my posts in Teams

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams, email

Here is what the email preferences page look like for Stack Overflow:

> [image]

> [image]

And here is how it looks like for Teams:

> [image]

Notice the lack of options to turn off weekly updates. You can either receive both the weekly updates and the critical emails (answers and comments on my posts) or nothing at all!

Hence I end up with weekly mails like this:

> [image]

> [image]

I rather not receive these (Frankly, don't care about the top contributors. And I am not experienced enough to answer unanswered questions). Please add a feature to turn these off without turning off critical updates like answers/comments on my posts.

Comment: Similar lament: [Prompt email notifications for a Content Health review gives urgency to a non-urgent task](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416514/prompt-email-notifications-for-a-content-health-review-gives-urgency-to-a-non-ur). The approach I took was to create an email filter for the email that was disruptive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to. Community digests are *not* sent as part of the Inbox emails bucket and any you are subscribed to should be appearing there so you can turn them on/off from within the Community Digests tab. Example:

[image: Community digests]

**Additional note:** If your team has been migrated to stackoverflowteams.com already, your community digests for that team will no longer appear in your settings on stackoverflow.com and you'll need to visit **Teams Digests** under **Account Settings** on the new domain.

---

The email you provided as an example, though, did not come from our Teams mail system (and I don't see that any emails have been sent to the email address for your account here). It came from an Enterprise instance, and you cannot control any of your email settings for an Enterprise instance on stackoverflow.com - we don't have access to any of that information. You'll need to login to Enterprise and go to your email settings there in order to manage your subscription preferences.